# How to force to load a specific orientation in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried to set a orientation with ScreenOrientation, in ionViewDidLoad() in a device and the localhost but i can't force the change.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-Test',
  templateUrl: 'Test.html'
})
export class TestPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
    this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_PRIMARY);
  }
}
```

Comment: On `config.xml` put this `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` and build again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
    this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
  }
```

OR

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
    this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_SECONDARY);
  }
```

Comment: I didn't see any changes and i'm testing it in my device.

Comment: On config.xml file put this code

 <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
 build again

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_PRIMARY)` line in **app.components.ts** files initializeApp() method before spash screen is hide.

Example : 
**app.components.ts**

```js
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
        this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE_PRIMARY).then(async ()=>{
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();

            this.rootPage="HomePage";
            // rest of your code goes here
        });
    });
}
```